# Can a pdf document pull information from a web service

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

Is it possible to generate a pdf document that pulls, say, contact information from a web-service and then displays it (and caches it). And if an internet connection is not available it displays the information it has cached.

The use case I'm looking to implement is:

1. User open a pdf document which connects to a web service and populates certain items (say phone numbers) and displays it to the user
2. Five days later, with the Internet connection broken, the user re-opens the document. The pdf reader detects it has no internet connectivity and servers up the last good version it has.

Question: Is there a way to do this robustly across pdf readers and if so how?

Comment: PDF is already a massively overbloated insecure pile of crap of a spec. Adding in arbitrary remote data grabbing will just make it even worse. if such a thing ever does get added in to the PDF spec, that'll be the day that PDFs are banned from my presence entirely.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for the frank assessment :-). So I guess what you're saying is that it is currently not in the realm of possibility to do such a thing?

Comment: consider how many malicious pdfs are floating around out there. giving pdfs to capability to fetch remote data would make it absolutely trivial to fetch custom attack packages tailored to the exact system the pdf's being executed on (yes, executed. pdfs are actually postscript programs). adobe's sandbox has proven to be a sieve already.

Comment: @MarcB I have some bad news for you, I am almost sure this is already possible with javascript embedded in a PDF file.

Comment: @yms, would you have any links to this type of capability?

Comment: Closed as not constructive? Seriously? This was a simple "yes or no" question, this is discouraging and disappointing.

Comment: @yms, I feel the same yms. It seems unless u ask how can I add 1+1 they close you down.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible by using [Adobe Javascript API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) and embedding your Javascript code in the PDF document using a Javascript-based action (see the [Adobe PDF Reference Document](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for details.)

For connecting to a web service, look at the [Javascript for Acrobat API Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf), specifically the part about SOAP (SOAP Properties and Methods, page 657).

About the "caching" feature, I strongly believe that is not going to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are hoping PDF viewers can take care of client-side functionality for you.  This is HIGHLY unlikely.  You need to consider other ways to provide such a feature - a client program that fetches the latest PDF if possible otherwise offers it's most recent version is what you are effectively needing.  PDF viewers won't provide this automatically.

Can you say more about your environment(s) to see if any other cleaver options are known?